# virtualenv is running from the wrong path?

Tags: python, heroku

I'm new to python and I have a couple of different apps that I have been making and now I'm playing around with deploying them to heroku. I'm currently trying to deploy an app called microblog and to do that, I need to install `gunicorn`. When I start my `venv` and `pip install gunicorn` it says that requirements have already been satisfied at `/myproject/venv/bin/python` but if `gunicorn` was installed, shouldn't requirements be satisfied at `microblog/venv/bin/python?`

When I start the venv, I'm typing `. venv/bin/activate` from the microblog folder